# Block route until consumer receives message

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration, eip

I have a route like this:

```
[producer1]--->[blocker]--->                 
                           |--->[aggregator]---> [consumer]
[producer2]---------------->
```

`Producer1` and `producer2` are pushing messages to the `aggregator`. If there are two messages with the same id then the aggregation is completed and the aggregated message will be routed to a consumer.

Is it possible to block the route after the `producer1` sends a message to the `aggregator`? Something like `wait until the consumer receives the aggregated message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible as the aggregator is two-legged. So what goes out of the aggregator is not linked to what goes in.

You can however build a java bean and use a CountDownLatch and then block after you have called the aggregator, and then signal a count down when you have an outgoing message from the aggregator.